# Javascript setting the SRC of an Img to whatever there is

Tags: javascript

I have a pattern for the names of the images. The second part (in the script below it is "whatever") will be used as additional information. This part is A-z. How can I load images with such names?

```
var createdImg = document.createElement('img');
createdImg.setAttribute('src','firstPart_' + whatever + '_.jpg');
```

Comment: An image filename can be any legal relative or absolute URL.  What is your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the element to the DOM. If you are using jquery, you can do something like this:

```
var whatever = 'test';
$("body").append("<img src='"+ 'firstPart_' + whatever + '_.jpg' +"'>");
```

here is the [bin](http://jsbin.com/rufekemapa/edit?html,js,output)